# My gaming build - any suggestions?

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, motherboard, memory, case

**Before you ask why I would spend around $800-850 dollars on a pc, it is just for a video. I'm not actually buying the parts.** (Though I wish I could build it; as I never got to before)

I'm making guides on buying PC parts; and presets on different budgets. Keep in mind that items like monitors, mice, keyboards, speakers etc. will be in a different guide/preset list; this is just the actual pc.

**Case:**
Name : Thermaltake Versa N21 Window Mid-Tower Chassis Case CA-1D9-00M1WN-00
Cost : 59.48
Why I choose it: Has sleek black look; Window; keeps usb(s) on top (I believe) for less accidents
**CPU:**
Name: AMD FD8320FRHKBOX FX-8320 FX-Series 8-Core Black Edition Processor
Cost: 140.81
Why I choose it: Has 8 cores which will be useful for the future, can be overclocked to 4.0 ghz for more work
**RAM:**
Name : Crucial Ballistix Sport 8GB Kit (4GBx2) DDR3 1600 MT/s (PC3-12800) CL9 @1.5V UDIMM 240-Pin Memory BLS2K4G3D169DS1J
Cost: 37.99
Why I choose it: 8 gbs of ram for 38 is really cheap. Furthermore it is clocked at 1600 which is good for DDR3 gaming.
**GPU:**
Name: MSI Computer NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970 GAMING 4G 4GB 256-Bit GDDR5 Graphics Card
Cost: 349.99
Why I chose it: The GTX is a well known card, and is powerful; just what I need for intense games and shaders.
**PSU:**
Name: Thermaltake TOUGHPOWER 1200W 80 PLUS GOLD Full Modular Power Supply PS-TPD-1200MPCGUS-1
Cost: 131.92
Why I chose it: You can buy the 1k watt PSU for $30 more. Great deal. The CPU takes 125 watts; the GPU recommends 850+ PSU, and the power is great for extreme overclocking (though not something I recommend)

Hard drive and optical disk drive:
[HDD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0033Z2BAQ)

[ODD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0088PUEPK)

What do you recommend I tweak?

REQUIRMENTS:

Stays under the 900 budget
Is compatible with other parts
Do not sacrifice a component for a different component (example removing odd for better hdd)
Is useful for the next 3-4 years.
You must explain the benefits of replacing the object.
Is not from an unknown brand in the middle of nowhere
Warranty for breaking the object (Let's pretend the user has no experience with computer building and is a first-timer)
Is from a well known website (preferably amazon but newegg will do well too)
Does not need to come with all the whistles and bells (but it can if you think they are useful)
If you suggest (example) DDR4; then you also need to give a requirement for the things that use DDR4 (MB, RAM, ECT.)
The case must have upgrade space (though I really like the case and don't see a better option right know)

Also, If you could come up with a name for the build then +1. No bloody names like Ripjaw but rather original like borinator (Austin Evans And Linus Tech Tips)

## Example:

I recommend the  [MSI SLI KRAIT](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00WB9MUX8)  as it supports 32 gigabytes of ram. It supports windows 10 and has an install manual. It supports your CPU so you do not have to worry about that. [Add more details however]

Comment: This question has been closed because it asks for too many things at one time. See the [quality guidelines](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/206/155) for more info and please consider condensing your question so it can be reopened. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is an energy-saving version of the `FX8320`, it just has an E at the End of it's name: `FX8320E`.

A 1200W-PSU is far enough for a 150W-GPU and a 105W-CPU, a smaller one like 650W-730W would also be far enough.

Also I wouldn't mix a AMD-CPU with a nVidia-GPU but nearly everybody says, that this doesn't do anything. The rest is fine. I don't know anythin about Thermaltake though and in my opinion nVidia is overpriced, so I would recommend Radeon on all times but that's my personal opinion.

## EDIT:

I am using the FX-8320E for 4-5 Months now and I'm very satisfied with it.

Comment: Thanks! The 750w version is 80 dollars and modular; in my opinion worth it.

Answer (score 2):

This build needs work.

---

You should wait out on buying AMD CPU's atleast till Zen comes out. They've just been re-releasing the same chip by overclocking it, and the 8320 is a slow chip. It's even slower than the 8350, which is the go-to chip for gaming AMD builds.

Also, because of a different architecture, AMD CPU's with a given frequency are far slower than Intel CPU's with the same frequency. AFAIK a 5GHz FX-8350 is comparable to a i5-4690K at stock(3.5 GHz). A normal 8350 is the equivalent of a mid-level i5 at best. I'd recommend a i5 4690K for gaming, you don't need 8 cores.

---

A GTX 970 consumes 145W of power. No way it'll need a 850W power supply. Maybe, if you're adding 3 cards in SLI, but not otherwise.

---

Thermaltake power supplies aren't that great, especially the older TR2 models. Get Antec or Seasonic, 80+ Gold rated power supplies. 750W should be enough for a fairly high end build. I recommend Seasonic.

---

For the motherboard, MSI is cheap, but not that great(power delivery circuitry is inferior to some brands). I'd recommend a Asus or Gigabyte Z97 based board. Get a Asus Z97-A or a Gigabyte Z97X Gaming 5, it'll allow you to add another 970 when you want.

---

As for the case, it looks mostly OK, except for the back panel. Do you have experience with this case? It seems that there is low clearance on the upper side of the motherboard from the back, which chould pinch cables; although it's hard to say from images without actually looking at it.
If you're looking at a case that won't cost too much money, I'd recommend the Corsair Carbide 300R, 400R or 500R. They're also mid-tower, and a 300R should come at the same price as yours.

As for the above answer from TesseractLabs, the AMD CPU/NVidia GPU and vice versa is all a myth. All of those are compatible. Although, if you go for a AMD FX CPU, you won't get integrated graphics.
Both Intel and AMD CPUs are fine with AMD and NVIDIA GPUs, although you can't use both NVIDIA and AMD GPU's in the same PC yet.